# How to use \textsubscript in package acronym

Tags: acronyms

I'm confused using the acronym package. i built the list as I am supposed to and it's working quite well. but I can't use \textsubscript in the acro-environment. for example

```
\begin{acronym}
 \acro{SML}{Specific Migration Limit}  % works fine
 \acro{SULT}{Sulfotransferase}  % works fine
 \acro{Cl\textsubscript{int}}{intrinsic Clearance}  %won't work at all
\end{acronym}
```

Anybody an idea how to get it working?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: sure, it's in german, but it should work.\documentclass{scrreprt}
 
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Text}
Texte, die eine \ac{Abk.} enthalten, die nicht im Duden steht, sollten ein \acl{Abk.}sverzeichnis haben. Eine \ac{Abk.}, die nicht verwendet wird, steht auch nicht im \acl{Abk.}sverzeichnis.
 
\chapter{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}
 \acro{Abk.}{Abkuerzung}
 \acro{z.B.}{zum Beispiel}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}

Comment: holy crap. sorry for that. How can I format the text in a comment?

Comment: You can't really "format" text in a comment, but if you enclose it in backticks (aka grave accents), it will highlight in a different font and color.  Also, you can edit your comments for up to 5 minutes after they are posted.

Comment: @Fukko It's better editing your question than adding code in a comment

Answer (score 6):

Use the syntax `\acro{acroym}[short name]{full name}` where `acronym` is a pure text sequence used in your tex file.  In this case `short name` is what gets displayed in your document, and it is here that you use the `\textsubscript`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{Text} 
Texte, die eine \ac{Abk.} enthalten, die nicht im Duden steht, sollten ein 
\acl{Abk.}sverzeichnis haben. Eine \ac{Abk.}, die nicht verwendet wird, steht 
auch nicht im \acl{Abk.}sverzeichnis, \ac{z.B.}, \ac{SML}, \ac{SULT}, \ac{CLint}

\chapter{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis} 

\begin{acronym} 
\acro{Abk.}{Abkuerzung} 
\acro{z.B.}{zum Beispiel} 
 \acro{SML}{Specific Migration Limit}  % works fine
 \acro{SULT}{Sulfotransferase}  % works fine
 \acro{CLint}[Cl\textsubscript{int}]{intrinsic Clearance}  % now it works
\end{acronym} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]